# multiple types of outputs from return statment

Tags: java, return, settings

I have a setting system and I want to be able to return the correct setting with the correct type of variable without making a new function for each.
So I have some code to save some settings.

```
Setting (String name, Object value){

}
```

This would work fine but I have many different types of settings to save. So I made sub-classes
For example:

```
BooleanSetting (String name, boolean value){
super(name,value);
}
```

Now I wanted to make 1 function that would work for all, but I'm not sure how.

In setting I have this method

```
public Object getValue(String name){
// I have some code here to search through the setting list for the setting with the name
// Lets call this setting setting
if(setting instanceof BooleanSetting){
return ect;
}
...
}
```

Now if I return anything it would still be an object so is this even possible. If not what is the next best solution.

What is the next step.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Basically you want to build getter setter without actually writing getters and setters right?

Comment: I want to be able to call a function that changes the output depending on the setting, so that In code i dont need to write a different function for each type of setting
like if booleansetting return boolean if stringSetting return string @mihirraj

Comment: Try to use Lombok. 
Not sure if that is what you are asking.
https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter